# Unable to assign mutliple values to array from html form that has mulitple checkboxes sharing same name attribute

Tags: html, forms, perl, cgi

I am attempting to read in values from an HTML form.  Two are simple scalars with separate "name" attributes.  However, another offers the user two checkboxes which share the same "name" attribute, but separate "values".  The user can choose one, the other, or both.  Therefore, I'd need to read this item in as an array.

The HTML file is separate from the perl script which it calls.  Below is a sample of the HTML to provide more details.

From form.html

```
<input name="first_name" type ="text">
<input name="last_name" type ="text">
<input name="classes" type="checkbox" value="ENG-101">
<input name="classes" type="checkbox" value="SOC-101">
```

This form calls a perl script.  The Perl script needs to be able to assign "first_name" and "last_name" into separate variables.  In addition, I need to be able to access each of the "classes".  One reason is, both of the classes cost $100.  If they click one box, I need to total the cost at $100, however, if they click both, I need to total the cost at $200.

So far, I have tried to do this:

```
#!/bin/perl
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;

my $Fname = $q->param('first_name');
my $Lname = $q->param('last_name');
my @classes = $q->param('classes');

my $totalCost = 0;

#This loop should iterate through the @classes array
#Each time it loops it'll add 100 to $totalCost

foreach my $i(@classes)
{
    $totalCost+=100;
}

#####down the script some ######

# Send an HTML reply page for review.
print <<EOT;
Content-type:text/html

<head>
<title>Confirm Your Order Information</title>
<style type="text/css">
    th, td, p {font-family : Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size : 10pt}
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff">


<p>
<h3 align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica">Order Summary</font></h3>

<table width="90%" align="center"><tr><td>

<p>
Please print a copy of this page for your records.
Here is a summary of your order. Please review your selections before   submitting your order.
If you need to make any revisions before submitting your order, use the BACK button on your browser to return to the form, make your changes, and resubmit the corrected form.

</p>

<P><font color=red><font size=+1>Your order will not be completed until you click on the "Submit Order" button at the bottom of this page. 

<P>


<table border=1 cellpadding=3 align="center">

<table>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2><b>SEND TO:</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>FIRST Name:</td><td>$Fname</td></tr>
<tr><td>FIRST Name:</td><td>$Fname</td></tr>

<tr><td>Var1:</td><td>@theCourse</td></tr>
<tr><td>Total Cost:</td><td>$totalCost</td></tr>
...
```

Am I on the right track with this?

I can read the $fName and $lName.  However, for some reason I can't get the array value to print or the $totalCost to display in the HTML form (it returns $0).  So, I think I'm not able to read the array in when both checkboxes are checked.

Please reply with any further questions or information I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Running your code in the debugging mode, i.e. with

```
use CGI '-debug';
```

with the following input piped to it:

```
first_name=John
last_name=Smith
classes=M
classes=M
```

produces the following output (after fixing the LAST name):

```
<tr><td colspan=2><b>SEND TO:</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>FIRST Name:</td><td>John</td></tr>
<tr><td>LAST Name:</td><td>Smith</td></tr>

<tr><td>Var1:</td><td>The course</td></tr>
<tr><td>Total Cost:</td><td>200</td></tr>
```

So, it seems the HTML that sends the values is wrong.

Also, you just want the number of classes times 100. No need to loop, just write

```
my $totalCost = 100 * @classes;
```

Comment: Even with the 
    my $totalCost = 110* @classes ---- It still doesn't display the right amount.  I'm thinking it isn't populating the array.  The full name of the "classes"  name is "class_1[]"  I'm wondering if the brackets are breaking it.